# How can I delete ghost database field between a special date?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with many user input and I want to delete ghost e-mail between a special date. I use this query and it seems to work very good:

```
DELETE u1 From tx_table u1 JOIN tx_table u2 USING (email) WHERE u1.tstamp < u2.tstamp
```

but I want to delete between a longer time. When I add 300 it seems to delete everything in my table:

```
DELETE u1 From tx_table u1 JOIN tx_table u2 USING (email) WHERE u1.tstamp < u2.tstamp+300
```

. How can I add 5 minutes to the tstamp with SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the mysql function TIMESTAMPADD:

```
TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, 5, u2.tstamp);
```

You may try to check it first and see what this returns:

```
select u2.tstamp,
       TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, 5, u2.tstamp) tstamp2
  from tx_table
```

Comment: WHERE TIMESTAMPADD( MINUTE , 5, u1.tstamp ) < u2.tstamp doesn't find anything but it doesn't delete anything either. Why add 5 min to u1 and not u2?

Comment: Ok, thanks, do you know what HAVING means? I need to delete only ghost email when another ajadceny list field has more then 2 rows for example DELETE count(u3.vote) as L, u1 From tx_table u1 JOIN tx_table u2 USING (email) join tx_table u3 USING (vote) WHERE u1.tstamp < u2.tstamp and L > 1?

Comment: Having is a keyword for making clauses with aggregate functions like having count(*) > 2.

Comment: Thanks, I think this timestamp thing isn't any good because I need also multiple emails. I can't delete every ghost email with the same  timestamp. I need to find this ajadceny list model.